# ¿Cómo leer archivo de texto y convertir datos en una lista <int>?

Tags: c#

estoy tratando de leer mi archivo de texto que contiene este tipo de datos:

```
257.9116
554.7042
250.8996
266.6049
262.9371
262.7673
257.9116
554.7042
250.8996
```

Lo que trato de hacer es leerlo y agregarlo a una `list <string>` para convertirlo a una `list <int>` para borrar los decimales y reescribirlo en un txt nuevo.

Use este código en un botón pero al momento de clickearlo comience el proceso pero en la linea de la conversión me dice  "La cadena no tiene el formato correcto"

```cs
private void cursor_track_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            List<string> lines = File.ReadLines(@"C:\EyeMatris\Coordenadas\CoordenadasX.txt").ToList();
            List<int> intlist = lines.Select(int.Parse).ToList() ;
            List<string> l2 = intlist.ConvertAll<string>(x => x.ToString());
            File.WriteAllLines("listaInt.txt", l2);
        }
```

Comment: si quieres convertir en un int, tienes que eliminar el caracter punto, como ejemplo en la primera linea tienes 257.9116 eso o lo cambias a 2579116 o lo cambias a dos lineas, pero asi no podras convertirlo, con un simple Replace(".","") ya eliminarias el punto

Comment: Entiendo pero lo necesito borrar los datos despues del punto, que quede 257 solamente

Comment: Hola amigo te tengo la respuesta te lo agrego en un momento saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma sencilla, es tratar la lista como `float` (de hecho lo es) y usar luego [`Math.Truncate()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.truncate?view=netframework-4.8) para quedarnos solo con la parte entera de cada uno de los elementos de la lista, que parece ser lo que buscas:

```
List<string> lines = File.ReadLines(@""C:\EyeMatris\Coordenadas\CoordenadasX.txt").ToList();
List<float> floatlist = lines.Select(float.Parse).ToList();
List<int> intlist = floatlist.Select(f => (int)Math.Truncate(f)).ToList();
```

Comment: Entiendo, entonces para pasarlo a limpio en un nuevo txt seria otra lista en string y usar un _File.WriteAllLines("listaInt.txt", );_ ?

Comment: Exactamente, transforma la lista de enteros a una de strings y luego WriteAllLines, como ya lo estás haciendo.

Comment: Funciona, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Hola no estoy muy seguro de si sea la mejor manera pero es como lo pude resolver.

```
  //Se lee la lista del archivo y se agrega a la lista de string
            List<string> lines = File.ReadLines(@"C:\EyeMatris\Coordenadas\CoordenadasX.txt").ToList();
            //se convierten los string a double
            List<double> intList = lines.Select(x => double.Parse(x)).ToList();
             //se convierten los double a INT32 para eliminar los puntos
        List<int> ConvertInt = intList.ConvertAll(Convert.ToInt32);
            //se regresa a una lista de texto para guardarlo en la ruta
            List<string> l2 = ConvertInt.ConvertAll<string>(x => x.ToString());
            //Se escribe en la misma ubicación pero con el nombre 2
            File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\EyeMatris\Coordenadas\CoordenadasX2.txt", l2);
```

De esta manera se hace un especie de redondeo, no se si es lo que necesitas si no seria hacer el split y tomar lo que nos interesa.

Saludos espero te sirva

Comment: Lo probe funciona perfectamente, Muchas gracias!!

Comment: De nada saludos, si esta fue la que te ayudo no olvides marcar la respuesta como correcta